# How do I stop my domain name maliciously redirecting?

Tags: apache, http, web, dns, domain-name

I have set up my website running on Apache2 on an Ubuntu server. I have two domain names from mydomain.com. I linked them up and they work, usually. But, often, when I try to load the domain name , I get redirected to another advertisement site.

When I load my server IP, it always displays the correct site.

Running: “**curl** *myip*” gives me the correct HTML.

Running: “**curl** *www.my-domain-name*” gives me...
`<HTML><FRAMESET><frame src=“searchvity.com/?dn=“my-domain-name”&pid=9PO1MNJ3”><FRAME src=“blank.html”></FRAMESET></HTML>`

Which is someone else. 
I do not know how this is happening, or what I could do. It has happened for a while, and doesn’t always happen.

I own two domains and they both redirect to the same site.